# Get a graph from all vertex with incident edges R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to obtain a subgraph from a graph, composed of all the vertex with incident edges starting from some vertices, and following the edges until there are no more incident edges. With the following code I only get the first neighbours

```
g <-   graph_from_literal( 1 -+ 4 -+ 5 -+ 8,2 -+ 5 , 3-+6-+7,  4+-3, 4-+8, 5 -+9, simplify = FALSE)
adjacent_vertices(g, V(g)[c("7","9")], mode="in")
```

I know that I should make some kind of loop but `adjacent_vertices` returns a list and I can't figure out how to make it.

For this example, the result should be

```
graph_from_literal( 1 -+ 4 -+ 5 ,2 -+ 5 , 3-+6-+7,  4+-3, 5 -+9, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Are you sure of your expected outcome; given that node 3 has no inward edges would you not expect the graph 3->6->7 to be unconnected to the other nodes?

Comment: To see use `sg = make_ego_graph(g, nodes = V(g)[c("7","9")], order=length(V(g)), mode="in")`; You can join them using `do.call(union, sg)`

Comment: It worked, the only thing I have to add is `do.call(igraph::union, sg)` you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make_ego_graph` can be used to find subgraphs in the neighbourhood of specific nodes.
You can search through the full graph by setting the `order` parameter in 
the function `make_ego_graph`.

Example

```
library(igraph)

# Your graph
g = graph_from_literal( 1 -+ 4 -+ 5 -+ 8, 2 -+ 5 , 3-+6-+7, 4+-3, 4-+8, 5 -+9, 
                        simplify = FALSE)

# Set the order equal to the number of nodes in the graph    
sg = make_ego_graph(g, nodes = V(g)[c("7","9")], order=length(V(g)), mode="in")

# This returns two subgraphs as node 3 has no inward edges and so the graph 3->6->7 
# is unconnected to the other nodes. You can join the subgraphs by using 
do.call(union, sg)
```